# How do I apply a custom style to a specific element only?

Tags: css, polymer, web-component

I'm developing a theme-able Polymer web component. As per the [custom-style](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-style) documentation I'm doing the following:

```
  <link rel="import" href="themes/my-element-theme.html">
  <style is="custom-style" include="my-element-theme"></style>
```

However, this is a blunt instrument as it applies the custom theme to all my elements.

One solution is to scope all my theme styles to a CSS class as follows:

```
:root custom-element.my-element-theme {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Myriad Pro', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

However, this makes it difficult to apply a custom style to a whole document.

Is there a way to apply custom styles to elements more selectively, say using CSS selectors? What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can use selectors to selectively apply styles to your themeable elements.

It's best to use custom properties and mixins and set their values to targeted elements. Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import" />
  <style is="custom-style">
    .container1 my-elem {
      --my-elem-span: {
        color: red;
      }
    }
    
    .container2 my-elem {
      --my-elem-span: {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container1">
    <my-elem>hello red</my-elem>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <my-elem>hello blue</my-elem>
  </div>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host { display: block; }
        
        :host span {
          @apply(--my-elem-span);
        }
      </style>
      
      <span><content></content></span>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-elem'
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

And you can externalize you styles like you did by placing the css rules in a separate styles module.

```
<dom-module id="my-elem-theme">
  <template>
    <style>
      .container1 my-elem {
        --my-elem-span: {
          color: red;
        }
      }

    .container2 my-elem {
      --my-elem-span: {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

You then import the way you do:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-elem-theme.html">
<style is="custom-style" include="my-elem-theme"></style>
```